# Unable to save/overwrite and excel file in python

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have the following code, it gets a CSV and should save it as an excel file.
If the file already exists, it should overwrite it with the new CSV.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook
from io import StringIO

    def save_to_excel(csv, type):
        csv_data_frame = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv))
        excel_file = pd.ExcelWriter(f"{type}_results.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')
        excel_file.book = Workbook()
        csv_data_frame.to_excel(excel_file, index=False, sheet_name="results")
        excel_file.save()
        excel_file.close()
```

However, I am getting the following warnings:

```
FutureWarning: Setting the `book` attribute is not part of the public API, usage can give unexpected or corrupted results and will be removed in a future version
  excel_file.book = Workbook()
save is not part of the public API, usage can give unexpected results and will be removed in a future version
  excel_file.save()
```

Not sure exactly what is the public API for these actions, can anyone assist?

Comment: You should use `ExcelWriter` as a context manager here. See the [`ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) docs for the recommended usage.

Comment: Why are you creating an empty workbook in the first place?

Answer (score -1):

I managed to fix it by using BigBens suggestion + removed the redundant Workbook and now everything works fine.

```
def save_to_excel(csv, type):
    csv_data_frame = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv))
    excel_file = pd.ExcelWriter(f"{type}_results.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')
    csv_data_frame.to_excel(excel_file, index=False, sheet_name="results")
    with excel_file:
        pass
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe `book` attr i protected or something like that but but disregarding it, the `.book` is already Woorkbook:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> ew = pd.ExcelWriter('some.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
>>> ew.book
<openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook object at 0x026748B0>
```

If you want to override `book` attr, try to do it using dedicated method - `load_workbook`.